# Angular input Validations not working

Tags: angularjs, validation

```html
<form name="LPform">
    <div class="form-row clearfix">
         <label class="lbl-fld" style="margin-left: 12%;">Email ID</label>
         <input class="mob-adj-inpbx" type="email" name="uemail" ng-model="useremail" placeholder=" me@example.com" ng-required="true"/>
         <div ng-show="LPform.uemail.$valid">Enter a valid email.</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here, I'm adding validations to 'email' and trying to display error message only when the user enters invalid email. However this is not working.

Comment: Can you please fiddle the proper angular code

Comment: sorry... didn't get u. I have added the controller and everything else on the page is working fine. "LPform.uemail.$valid" is not working. I'm not sure if I have to add any method or variable in js file

Comment: i mean to say tha please share the whole html and javascript code. So that others can help it out. Also make a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I suppose you want to show the error message if the input is invalid so

   `ng-show="!LPform.uemail.$valid"`
2. Maybe you forgot to bind it to a scope variable? cause it seems to work fine.

```js
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.useremail = '';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <form name="LPform">
      <div class="form-row clearfix">
        <label class="lbl-fld">Email ID</label>
        <input class="mob-adj-inpbx" type="email" name="uemail" ng-model="useremail" placeholder=" me@example.com" ng-required="true" />
        <div style="font-size: 11px; color: red; margin: 5px 65px;" 
             ng-show="!LPform.uemail.$valid">Please enter a valid email.</div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It worked fine with ng-show="LPform.uemail.$error.email"